# Share selected select with another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to  to share a selected option with another controller (And have it update when I select a new option). Something that would work like the 2-way data binding between controllers.

I've attempted this by setting up a factory like so

```
.factory("shareObjective", function($scope){

     var shareObjective = {};
     return {
         shareObjective: shareObjective,
     };
})
```

Then I inject this into the controller and bind it to the model of the select like so

```
$scope.selectModel = shareObjective.shareObjective;
```

I seem to be having some trouble getting this to work. I Basically just want to share the selected option (it's .name to be precise) with another controller and am struggling to do so. My first step was to get it to share into the factory to begin with, but I seem to be having no luck attempting this. Should I be using something like the $broadcast to keep the stream of information open? Thanks!

Edit - here's a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/L5lz4etQ7mUEhf9viNOk?p=preview

Comment: can you setup a plunker.. it should work as is

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Is it that the value isn't updating when it changes in the factory?

Comment: I'll make a plunkr. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this won't work by default because you use two different scopes thus different ngModels.
Using a service also won't help because even if a click on a select with a ngModel in one scope will trigger a digest loop in that scope, it won't trigger it in the other scope.
As you suggest yourself you need to somehow notify the other scope to update itself, and yes you can do this through events (`$broadcast` and `$on`):

Both controllers contain

```
<select
    ng-model="foo"
    ng-options="foo for foo in foos"
></select>
```

And this is the JS:

```
var foos = [
    'foo1',
    'foo2',
    'foo3'
];

function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.foo = foos[0];
    $scope.foos = foos;

    // detect broadcasts from other controllers and set our value to the one we received
    $rootScope.$on('foo-event', function(e, data) {
        $scope.foo = data;
    });

    // detect when foo changes and broadcast it's value
    $scope.$watch('foo', function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('foo-event', $scope.foo);
    });
}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', MyCtrl]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', MyCtrl]);
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6510/)

Notice that my code does not use a single controller, just a single controller implementation. You can write your own `MyCtrl1` and `Myctrl2` implementations that both have this code inside.

Also, while it would look like this generates an infinite loop between `$watch` and `$on`, it does not. `$scope.foo = data;` does not trigger `$watch`,

Comment: $broadcast sends the event down the scope tree, so you can emit it from any common parent of both controllers. $scope.$parent should do just fine.